# eve REST API and how to post a role list for role based authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, pycharm, eve

I'm trying to recreate the role-based authentication like in http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html#b-user-roles-access-control

The API is running and I can add accounts without the role, but when I implement the roles like in the above link and try to post a role via Pycharms REST client I get:

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": 
  {"roles": "must be of list type"}, 
  "_error": 
    {"message": "Insertion failure: 1 document(s) contain(s) error(s)", "code": 422}}
```

I tried a lot of different ways to post the roles like variations of `roles[]=user`, but if I put anything else than just roles in the input field of the REST client, I get something like "no field roles[], roles required" etc...

Can someone please help me post roles as a list?

PS: When I try using something else like "Advanced REST client" or "POSTMAN", I get:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1465, in find_handler
    handler = handler_map.get(cls)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2016 14:29:42] "POST /accounts HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the same schema as on example so roles key must contain a list of roles, not string. I don't know how you exactly send your request but I guess that you add this param to URL which is not correct. According to presented schema you should send POST request with payload such as this:

`{"username":"User","password":"0000","roles":["user","superuser"]}`

Also remember to send content type header:

`Content-Type: application/json`

If you use PyCharm REST client your configuration should look like this
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what i needed. Works now!